# How is Oracle Solaris 11.x licensed?

Tags: solaris, oracle, licensing

can this be used in a corporate LAB? as a storage server for DEV&TEST, not production.

free to use for:

1. Developing
2. Testing
3. Prototyping
4. Demonstrating your applications

how are the repository, packages supported? meaning can i always connect to Oracle Solaris11 repos for most recent packages?

here is the oracle license terms: *"......including but not limited to distribution of the Programs or any use of the Programs for your internal business purposes (other than developing, testing, prototyping and demonstrating your applications) or for any commercial production purposes, you must obtain a valid license permitting such use."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you mean Solaris 11 Express. It is not a beta release but a regular and fully supported release. It is licensed the same way as Solaris 10.
If you use the OTN license (free for developing, testing, prototyping, demonstrating your applications), you'll have no support or updates. You need a valid support contract to get them.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/solaris-cluster-express-license-167852.html

Comment: by updates i mean access to repository for additional packages, is that available ?

Comment: Sure. These aren't updates but just part of the release.

Answer (score 1):

Newer Oracle Solaris 11.3 have free download under page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/install-2245079.html

Corresponding license agreement: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/solaris-cluster-express-license-167852.html have text:

> LICENSE RIGHTS
>
> Except for any included software package or file that is licensed to you by Oracle under different license terms, we grant you a perpetual (unless terminated as provided in this agreement), nonexclusive, nontransferable, limited License to use the Programs only for the purpose of **developing**, **testing**, **prototyping** and **demonstrating** your applications, and **not for any other purpose**. If You are an educational institution vested with the power to confer official high school, associate, bachelor, master and/or doctorate degrees, or local equivalent, (“Degree(s)”), You may also use the Programs as part of Your educational curriculum for students enrolled in Your Degree program(s) **solely as required for the conferral of such Degree** (collectively “Educational Use”).

So if you are hacker on or learner of Solaris - welcome to use it!

Answer (score 0):

Solaris 11 Express is fully supported if you have a valid oracle support contract.